# How to run a project that is inside some subfolders on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

Please see the attached image for the project structure. Currently its the run button is greyed out. I know that I can from files open only the folder from where the android studio project starts but then version control will not work.

Comment: where is the image ...?

Comment: Sorry, added it now

Comment: Does Gradle build succeed? And can you change the view to "Android"?

Comment: Cant change the view to android, cant build gradle also

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `MainActivity` (or what ever name you use for your launching activity) and say `Run`. It will automatically setup the run configuration for you in Android Studio.